# computer beeps then crashes from this C++ code

Tags: c++, crash

i was trying to hold an image into a string (png) then i was going to try and view it using sdl why does the computer beeps then crashes when i try to output the string (excuse me im a newbie)

```
#include "http.h"
#include<iostream> 
#pragma comment (lib,"winhttp.lib")

using namespace std;
http_connect c; 

int main()
{
    c.open_session(L"maps.googleapis.com");
    c.request(L"/maps/api/staticmap?center=-15.800513,-47.91378&zoom=11&size=200x200&sensor=false");
    c.read_data();
    std::cout<<c.data();
    c.end_connection();
    system("pause");
};
```

if you want the full code (including http class) [go here](http://pastebin.com/jKTCMygL)

Comment: I don't really want anyone's full code, but I'd rather want *you* to use your debugger and narrow the problem down so you can ask a more focused question!

Comment: Whatever you're getting from c.data() has binary data (you said you're reading a .png file). Outputting that to `cout` is causing the beeps (in particular, `\x7` bytes. As to the crash, I think it shouldn't *crash* but rather take very long to finish writing its output, due to the long sequence of beeps.

Comment: no infact i tried the code on 2 computers one beeps then crashes and the other beeps only but in both cases the output was fast

Comment: Can you narrow down to which line it is crashing on? I don't think printing the PNG to stdout should cause it to crash. It would seriously mess up the display of your console, but I don't think it would crash. Can you give us a better description of what your crash is like? Does Windows display an error? Does the console just go away with no warning?

Comment: it crashes on the cout line ,the computer beeps several times then displays an error then shutdowns

Comment: If the PNG data does not contain any NUL-characters, cout won't know when to stop outputting the string and accesses memory out of bounds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is you are trying to print binary data (png) as a string.  That will cause lots of beeping like you describe.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a Windows application, you should run that code in the VS (or otherwise) debugger and step over each of the lines in `main`. The line where you get lots of beeping will be the line that you need to look into.

This will most likely be the `cout` line since printing out binary data to standard output will probably involve quite a few CTRL-G characers (the BEL character). If so, re-run and examine the contents of `c` before trying to print out the data.

This will both solve your immediate problem *and* teach you how to debug code on your own.